# All my apache site use wrong SSL certificate after openvpn and openvpn-as install

Tags: debian, apache2

I did the following on my debian 9 server:

```
  494  apt-get install openvpn
  495  cat /etc/debian_version 
  496  apt update && apt -y install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg
  497  wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -
  498  echo "deb http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian stretch main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
  499  apt update && apt -y install openvpn-as
```

Since these operations, all my apache2 website use a wrong certificate:

[image]

Where can I find apache2 config that does this ? Or what is the process which permit to find the concerned certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed openvpn and openvpn-as packages, reload apache2 and problem solved.